# Show message if request takes too long

Tags: angular, typescript

How to show a message if a request takes too long. If the request takes longer than 10 seconds, display a message to wait until the request completes.

```
getData(url, requestParams) {
  return this.restService.get('url', requestParams)
}

showMessage(time) {
 setTimeout( () => {
     console.log("the request is taking more than 10s, please wait.")
 }, time)

}
```

I tried with setTimeout without sucess.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62466280/angular-2-http-request-show-loading-spinner-for-a-minimum-duration-for-both-s might help

Comment: Whatever answers you get, make sure you try it on a VM or PC with 2Gb memory or a system with a bad network link.  Sometimes they take between 10-30 seconds to pop up a dialog box.  Sometimes the browser can take 1 minute to start and you could be waiting 30s to a minute for the browser to redraw itself.  Just waiting that minute will exceed your 10 s and may force a popup, which won't appear for another 30s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intercept seems to be well suited for this case.

```
 requestTimout;

showMessage(time) {
    clearTimeout(this.requestTimout);
    this.requestTimout = setTimeout( () => {
        console.log("the request is taking more than 10s, please wait.");
        }, time)
}
  
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    this.showMessage(10000);

    return next.handle(authReq).pipe(
        tap(resp => {
            if (resp instanceof HttpResponse) {   
                clearTimeout(this.requestTimout);
            }
        })
    );
  };
```